# Can Windows PE 2.0 support the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, winpe

I'm interested in building a PC for a car that will boot off of a USB flash drive. I'm planning on using [Windows PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment) 2.0 for it with the GUI being written in C# or VB.NET.

Obviously, for this to work, I'd need to have [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 2.0 or later installed. Understanding that .NET is not included by default, is there a way to package .NET 2.0 with Windows PE 2.0 in such a way as to allow my [GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) application to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you, but here's a [.NET 2.0 plug-in](http://www.colinfinck.de/en/peplugs/dotnetfx20pe/) which requires "PE Builder 3.x or Microsoft Windows PE 2004 or 2005".

Answer (score 2):

> Windows PE does not support the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework or the Common
>   Language Runtime (CLR).

Source: *[What is Windows PE?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093.aspx)* (MSDN).