# Managed code in WinPE

Tags: managed-c++, managed-code, winpe

If I want to run a program in windows PE (Vista or 7) am I not allowed to use any level of managed code?

Can I only have c++ code that doesn't reference any dotNet code?

How can I interact with windows? Do I have to use user32.dll type files to carry out various operations?

Comment: Update: WinPE 4.0 supports .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: See also [Can Windows PE 2.0 support the .NET framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137817/can-windows-pe-2-0-support-the-net-framework)

Windows PE is a very limited bit of windows before windows proper. It stands to reason that vast parts of the windows in  the WIN32 subsystem will not be available. However [this page discusses coding with PE (though its limited to XP embedded)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940844(WinEmbedded.5).aspx). And [this](http://www.msfn.org/board/lofiversion/index.php/t83088.html) discusses some ui aspects under PE and possibly ways of getting access to the windows libraries.

It may be possible to [self host the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx) but I doubt it. Might make an interesting challenge. Let us know how you get on.